# How to connect a AngularJS app to Kinvey?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, client-side, kinvey

How do I connect a AngularJS app to a Kinvey backend in an easy way?

Comment: This question is a little generic. Can you be more specific? Which APIs, what use case, etc.

Comment: Ahh sorry. I don't mind if it's the REST API or javascript library to be honest. Whichever is easier. For use cases, I'm thinking general use, fetching and saving data, user management.

Comment: [https://gist.github.com/aaronksaunders/5573292](http://bit.ly/13ui4V1) [recent sample angularJS sample I wrote with Kinvey](http://bit.ly/13ui4V1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late to the conversation, but I have created a library for AngularJS that provides full support to Kinvey using the REST API.

https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-kinvey

Comment: Note: You should now use the official Kinvey integration: http://devcenter.kinvey.com/angular/guides

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I work at Kinvey.

I have been working on an app that uses angular in my free time, you can see the source to the services I have created that communicate with Kinvey. https://github.com/InnCrisis/InnCrisis/blob/master/public/coffeescripts/adminServices.coffee

A small snippet of javascript to handle the registration of a new user in Kinvey.

```
register = function(username, password, name) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  new Kinvey.User.create({
    username: username,
    password: password,
    name: name
  }, {
    success: function(user) {
      $rootScope.$apply(null, function() {
        deferred.resolve(user.toJSON(true));
      });
    },
    error: function(e) {
      $rootScope.$apply(null, function() {
        deferred.reject(e);
      });
    }
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Since the Kinvey javascript API will make changes that are not tracked by angular you need to do a $scope.$apply of the results.

Comment: Consider using plain JS - it would help more people. Why use something that only helps a sub-domain of JS users?

Comment: Thanks Alan, I just updated the example to be Javascript instead of Coffeescript.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a quick tour of their site, it seems Kinvey has a RESTful API, which makes things fairly straightforward. Going cross-domain, you'll need to find out if the Kinvey server is [CORS compliant](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) (returns appropriate headers allowing for cross-domain access) or if not, you'll need to use Angular's $http.jsonp to GET the data (jsonp only supports GET).